# I deleted and reinstalled Batman Arkham Knight from epic and when I booted the game, my saves were gone. Is there a way to recover my data?

Tags: steam, batman-arkham-knight, epic-games-launcher

I did save some of my data a while back to another folder but I'd like to get all of my timed records and progress back. I noticed that in the `This PC/Documents/WB Games/Batman Arkham Knight/SteamID/SaveData/Backup` folder there is a bunch of save data backup files.

Of note is that I own the game on epic and did not own the game on steam, and yet there are still apparently backup saves in a folder labeled `SteamID`. However, these files have a date at the end of their file extension (i.e. `*.sgm_xx_xx_20xx`).

When I get rid of the date extension, the game recognizes the file as save data, but says that it's corrupted and shows 0% game progress. Is there any way to make this data work with the epic version of the game? 
Is there any other way to recover save data after deleting and reinstalling the game? Would I be able to access this data if I bought the steam version of the game?

Update:
I bought the game on steam and unfortunately, it didn't recognize the save data in that folder. I tried editing the file extension to make it a .sgm file (rather than a `.sgm_xx_xx_20xx`) and it still didn't recognize it.

The steam version didn't recognize it at all, which makes me wonder if there's an online check or something that's preventing me from using my own files from the `SaveData` folder.

Importantly, I converted the most recent of these save data backups and my own manual backup (which works but is outdated) to .txt files to compare them. It looks like the backup files in the `SteamID` folder is a valid save file, it is very similar in its contents to the old one, with just some changes to some characters and lines.

Due to this and the filesize, I am convinced that this automatic backup is a valid save file and my chance at getting my data back. However, I can't seem to get it to work with either a steam or epic version of the game, and it still has that pesky file extension (`.sgm_xx_xx_20xx`).

I think this can actually save my data, but I need help figuring out how. How can I get this file to work with the game? Is there any other way to restore lost data?

Comment: If it was a steam game and cloud saves were enabled you'd be able to pull it back from there. I'm not sure if Epic games has a similar feature.

Comment: @Sorean Epic Games Launcher do have a same feature. It's default state is Enabled, so if OP didn't set it disable, it should pull OP's save data from cloud.

Comment: @Skye-AT Epic Games Launcher does have such a feature (and I definitely didn't do anything to turn it off) but I don't know if Batman Arkham Knight has such a feature with epic. It doesn't seem to have such a switch in the pull down bar for cloud saves in this game. The wierd part is that despite all this there seems to be backup saves in a folder labeled "steam". They do seem to be for the correct game and have the correct "last played" dates, too.

Comment: I did try using rename to get rid of the date in the file extension and turn it into a .sgm file. The epic games version recognizes it as a save game but doesn't retrieve any data (everything says its a 0% or not completed) and the game says that it's corrupted.